# Extract Type for Discriminator Values from Union

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
const disconnected = () =>
  ({
    type: 'DISCONNECTED'
  } as const);

const connected = () =>
  ({
    type: 'CONNECTED'
  } as const);

type Events = ReturnType<typeof disconnected | typeof connected>;
```

Is there any way to extract a Type from `Events` that is equal to the set of values from the `type` property of each member of the union. I'd expect to get back something like `type EventTypes = 'DISCONNECTED' | 'CONNECTED'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very simple way of doing that is this:

```
type Events = ReturnType<typeof disconnected | typeof connected>['type']; //'DISCONNECTED' | 'CONNECTED'
```

Comment: Can you explain why the dot accessor (`.`)  does not work in that case ?

Comment: You're awesome! For some reason I assumed it had to be more complicated than this with a `Pick` or `Extract` or something. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Nicolas that's how index types work in TS, you can check them here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types